# Need an element to have a background image that'll be responsive

Tags: html, css

So far, I've been able to mostly style elements with CSS3 for gradients etc. I've now reached a point where a certain style can not be done exactly how I'd like to recreate this: [image]

So I'm using that image as a background image for a div. Now the issue is, using the `background-size:100%` property and value, of course allows the image to stretch but it also slightly moves it's position and becomes a bit blurry. I'd like for the image to be able to be resized and stay in its position while not losing its quality so much although I think such a thing may be impossible. I'm wondering what the best way to go about this would be to get close to what I want.

Comment: For what it's worth, he's a semi-close CSS3 solution. It's not perfect but if you want to use it feel free. http://codepen.io/bbuck/pen/DKlvb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be a bit hasty to dismiss CSS... You should be able to replicate that using something along these lines:

```
.css {
    width: 98%;
    height: 13%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #2c3439 0%, #2c3439 50%, #667680 70%, #5d6f7b 100%);
    border-top-left-radius: 15px 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px 8px;
    box-shadow: inset 3px 5px 5px #95aab9, inset -1px -5px 7px #242b2f, 3px 2px 6px #777;
}
```

If you are certain you want to go the image route, try using something like `background-size: contain;` to maintain the aspect ratio of the image, while filling to at least one of the extents of the container.

You can use width and height and padding to keep the container as close to that aspect ratio as possible.

Check out this demo, showing both my CSS version of your image, and the `background-size` property:

http://jsfiddle.net/GfEA7/

Comment: I agree, wish I had seen this one first. Thanks a lot Josh.

Answer (score 0):

Your image isn't losing quality.  It's looking different and sometimes more fuzzy because the aspect ratio is being changed.  To prevent this from happening, you can allow the user to only change either the height or the width at a time, but not both at the same time.

When the user changes the height, the width is automatically adjusted to keep the current aspect ratio.  When the user changes the width, the height is automatically adjusted.

Comment: I'm trying background-size:100% 27px; so the height is set. Any way to do something like this without losing the aspect ratio or without having the effect of a lost aspect ratio?